# Access consumer from ConsumerRebalanceListener in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I need to use ConsumerRebalanceListener and find that it's possible to register it by containerProperties.setConsumerRebalanceListener method. I need consumer instance in balancer listener for getting positions of partitions (consumer.position()) and for overriding the fetch offsets of consumer (consumer.seek()), but I couldn't find way how to have access to consumer instance.

**Edited**

Raised a GH issue, and here is the link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/304

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you have to use [`ConsumerSeekAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#seek) implementation from your target listener:

> The first is called when the container is started; this callback should be used when seeking at some arbitrary time after initialization. You should save a reference to the callback; if you are using the same listener in multiple containers (or in a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) you should store the callback in a ThreadLocal or some other structure keyed by the listener Thread.
>
> When using group management, the second method is called when assignments change. You can use this method, for example, for setting initial offsets for the partitions, by calling the callback; you must use the callback argument, not the one passed into registerSeekCallback. This method will never be called if you explicitly assign partitions yourself; use the TopicPartitionInitialOffset in that case.

Comment: Thanks, for reply Artem. But I need to handle ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsRevoked callback too, where I need to get position of partition for storing it to my database.

Comment: OK. I see your point. Starting with version `2.0` we provide a new `Consumer` argument for the target listener: https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/27/spring-for-apache-kafka-2-0-milestone-1-available. But OTOH you might just consider to track `offset` for each message and really store into DB when `onPartitionsRevoked()` happens.

Comment: However I see your point and we really might need to add one more callback method to the `ConsumerSeekAware` and provide positions for the partitions revoked. Feel free to raise a GH issue on the matter with the link to this SO topic: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues

Comment: do you know when spring Kafka 2.0 will be released?

Comment: Somewhere just after Spring 5.0 GA release